# Using multiple textboxes to search database Asp.net

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that pull data from database using textbox. However, I've added another textbox that would also give them another option to pull the same data. A user can either use the id number or the address to conduct the search. But say I enter data in the id textbox and leave the address textbox empty its pulling all the records; not the record based on the id number entered; however if I leave the id textbox empty and enter into the address textbox it returns the one record needed.

Stored Procedure

```
select id, name, age, address, telephone where 
  WHERE id= @id
  OR ISNULL(@id, '') = '' and address= @address
  OR ISNULL(@address, '') = ''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need parentheses:

```
SELECT id, name, age, address, telephone 
WHERE ( ISNULL(@id, '') = '' AND ISNULL(@address, '') = '' )
  OR  ( ISNULL(@id, '') = '' AND address = @address )
  OR  ( ISNULL(@address, '') = '' AND id = @id )
  OR  ( id = @id AND address = @address )
```

Comment: I've tried your answer; however if I enter the id and address that goes with it. it doesn't return any result

Comment: Thanks actually got before you edited but nonetheless thanks